# itemtype attribute error in validate

Tags: html, w3c, w3c-validation

itemtype attribute error in validate

itemtype attribute from google webmasters http://s11.cc/aeyd

**this soluotion for facebook like button og attribute
http://s11.cc/xn0x*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a **HTML5 doctype**, the attribute `itemtype` should validate.

This will define the HTML5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```